# title of a section breakes an is on two pages

Tags: titles, titlesec, section-titles

I use `\usepackage{titlesec}` to create some nice titles. For sections I use this setup:

`\titleformat{\section}[block] {\normalfont\sffamily}{\bfseries\thesection}{.50em}{\titlerule[0.75pt]\\[.8ex]\bfseries}`

The problem is that the title breakes at the end of a page. If the page is full with text an then the section-title should be there, the titlerule is on one page and the actual title on the next page. How can I prevent this?

An actual MWE is the following code. It produces exactly the problem I want to prevent.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,a4paper, xcolor=dvipsnames]{scrartcl}
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
{\normalfont\sffamily}{\bfseries\thesection}{.50em}{\titlerule[0.75pt]\\[.8ex]\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\blindtext[2]

\section{test 2}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.
Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec
ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh
lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit.
Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat.
Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent
blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.
Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.
Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec
ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh
lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit.
Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat.
Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent

\section{test 3}

\blindtext[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{\section{test 3}}`  I could do this automatically, but not using titlesec.

Comment: It works perfectly fine, thanks a lot :)